# Is there a way to index through objects dnyamically in Scriban with C#?

Tags: c#, xetex, scriban

Working on a PDF generator and it uses the Templating Engine Scriban and LaTeX.  Although I cannot seem to reference the C# object Scriban is trying to read via index notation (use the data at this index of the array).  I mean something like this:

```
{~for index in 0..document.template_data.tables.size~}} 
  {{ document.template_data.tables[index].data_matrix }}
{{ end }}
```

I get: `Object document.template_data.tables[index] is null` which ultimately means for whatever reason the compiler cannot retrieve that object.

---

Q: Is the data actually in the objects?
A: Yes, I hardcoded in numbers like 0 and 1 and got relevant data. This was the case for two of the fields I was trying to access.  The issue is trying to dynamically generate the tables.

Q:  Does the array have a size?
A:  I've looped through in scriban with just the size spitting out.  There are 5 tables.

Q: Did you do research?
A: Yes, here are some people on github telling people the issue has been fixed

[Does Scriban support .NET Object Indexers?](https://github.com/lunet-io/scriban/issues/159)

[Accessing object property using indexer notation](https://github.com/lunet-io/scriban/issues/116)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is actually to do with the index out of bounds. You are looping through 0 - the size of the table.  In other words, the object is null because you are trying to access past the last entry. I created some super simple POCOs to fill out the objects similar to your code.

```
public class Document
{
    public Data TemplateData { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public List<TableRow> Tables { get; set; }
}
public class TableRow
{
    public string DataMatrix { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the updated script to loop through the tables

```
var bodyTextSub = @"{{~for index in 1..document.template_data.tables.size ~}} 
{{index - 1}}: {{ document.template_data.tables[index-1].data_matrix }}
{{ end }}";
var doc = new Document
{
    TemplateData = new Data
    {
        Tables = new List<TableRow>
        {
            new TableRow {DataMatrix = "This works!!"},
            new TableRow {DataMatrix = "Row 2"},
            new TableRow {DataMatrix = "Row 3"},
            new TableRow {DataMatrix = "Row 4"},
            new TableRow {DataMatrix = "Row 5"}
        }
    }
};
var template2 = Template.Parse(bodyTextSub);
var result2 = template2.Render(new {document = doc});
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Here is the result:

```
0: This works!!
1: Row 2
2: Row 3
3: Row 4
4: Row 5
```